# Preview PDF after running has a short delay (about 5 seconds) on Windows 10

Tags: pdftex, texworks, viewers

I use TeXworks to compile a file with the default option: pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX. I am using Version 0.6.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64 bit).

The problem is the following: after making changes in my file and compiling it by clicking the Typeset button, the viewer  shows the updated version only after some delay (about 5 seconds); in other words the syncing is delayed.

The tool settings are:

```
--pdf
--synctex=1
--clean
$fullname
```

and the "View PDF after running" option is checked. These are the same settings I have on another computer running Windows 7. But on Windows 7 I don't have that delay. Also when I browse the PDF in the viewer, sometimes shows the message "page rendering" in particular when I move from one page to another.

This is a bit annoying and delays my work.

Any ideas about what the problem might be and how to solve it?

Comment: If you do the same settings in both your computers, and you get the delay in one computer, then it depends on your system, not LaTeX, so it is off-topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: The question is which setting to compare. I only looked at the tool settings mentioned in the question. If it is possible to rule out that the problem is related to the OS, then I would have an answer.

Comment: Does that mean the compilation has finished and *then* the ~5 sec. delay starts? Is this the same for all files? Does it maybe depend on the size of the PDF? I assume we are talking about TeXworks' own previewer?

Comment: Yes. After the compilation has finished start counting ~5 second then the previewer shows the new PDF. The file I talk about now is 430 KB, and I observe this in several files with different sizes. Yes, I talk about TeXworks own previewer.

Comment: How do you know the compilation is finished? Do you see the rolling log output or can you tell by the button turning green again?

Comment: Yes, I see both.

Comment: It sounds like a miktex specific problem so open an issue in the miktex issue tracker.

Comment: I agree with Ulrike. But before you do that you may want to make sure your system is updated completely (run the updater twice in admin and user mode). My TeXworks says it's 0.6.2 (MikTeX 2.9.6960). You may also want to try and reproduce the issue on another Win 10 machine if you have access to one. I double checked on my system and I can't see a non-negligible delay.

Comment: Many TeX settings could accumulate delays the obvious one is the location on the system path. I try to keep Tex Live engine at end of path (slow & steady fall back) but when using MiKTeX pre-set it in Path (faster if not updating) equally if texmf paths are deep searching added packages  can add more delays so optimise for your every day usage. Other factors  bitness (32/64) & rendering delay on a small file can be indication it is heavily compressed and decompressor is working overtime (compare  difference in CPU usage between the 2 machines as well as if the tex produces equal pdf on both.

Comment: Ps forgot to mention that the antivirus on two systems is a very likely candidate for stalling handback of control to the viewer (but that is not tex engine related :-)